# Using diff command, ignore character at end of line

Tags: linux, unix, compare, diff

I'm not entirely sure what sort of diff command I'd do to match what I need. But basically I have two different directories full of files that I need to compare and outline the changes of. But in one set of files they basically have a '1' at the end of the line.

An example would be if comparing these two objects

File1/1.txt

```
I AM IDENTICAL
```

File2/1.txt

```
I AM IDENTICAL 1
```

So I'd just want the diff command to leave out the '1' at the end of the line and show me the files which actually have changes. So far I came up with something like

```
diff  file1/ file2/ -rw -I "$1" | more
```

but that doesn't work.

Apologies if this is an easy obvious question.

Comment: That is not what `diff` is made for, I doubt there is a direct solution. Instead I suggest you use something like `sed` to remove unwanted parts of the input, then pipe the result into the `diff` command.

Comment: @arkascha Any suggestions for how I'd go about doing that. I'm not too familiar with the sed command.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of files and/or size is not that much, you can eyeball the differences and simply use `vimdiff` command to compare two files side by side

```
vimdiff File1/1.txt File2/1.txt
```

Otherwise, as [arkascha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1248114/arkascha) suggested, first you need to modify your files to eliminate the ending character(s) before comparing them.

Comment: I'm comparing 1000's of files, so unfortunately vimdiff isn't really an option. Do you know how I'd go about using sed to modify all the files at once to remove the '1' at the end of the lines.

Comment: If all the lines in your files include the character 1, you can use the following sed command to remove it: `sed 's/1$//' input.txt > output.txt`. [edit]: Obviously you need to have for-loops (maybe in a bash script file) over entire files and apply this command to all the filenames (input.txt).